# Is There a Way to Specify Limits On a Factorial

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

If I want to be able to express a factorial -- let's say "$20$!" -- but with upper and lower limits such that the factorial is evaluated from Upper Limit, $n_1=20$, through a Lower Limit, $n_2=10$, for example, is there a convenient mathematical function that performs that?

Obviously, a simple subtraction operator won't do much since twenty-factorial from $n_1=20$ to $n_2=10$ does not equal either of the two possible subtraction quantities you could use:

*** $20!$ [Conditions: Evaluated from $n_1=20$ through $n_2=10$]

$= (20 \times 19\times 18  \times \cdots  \times 10)$ does not equal $(20-10)!$ or $(20!)-(10!)$

I'm very interested in the use of such a function. Obviously, a used lower valued numbers for simplicity but, in practice, I'm not always afforded such nice numbers and I need an easy way to express a restricted factorial.

Comment: $20!/9! {}{}{}$

Comment: In school this is called $P(20,9)$ or $P^{20}_9$ or ${}^{20}P_9$ or some related names.

Answer (score 4):

You know from the definition of factorial, that $n! = n\cdot (n-1)!$ . Therefore, you have

\begin{array}
2\frac{5!}{2!} &= \frac{5\cdot 4\cdot 3 \cdot 2!}{2!}\\
&=5\cdot 4\cdot 3
\end{array}
as an example.

In general, if $r<n-1$

$$\frac{n!}{r!} = n \cdot (n-1) \cdot ... \cdot (n-r+1)$$

Comment: Thank you. This  is very helpful. I've been familiar with permutations and some basic combinatorics but it's unusual and I would not have thought to revert to the permutation as a means of embodying a "restricted factorial" (i.e., with bounds), so to speak, since I'm so much more accustomed to the application of the permutation in applications of probability theory.

Comment: Well, you should notice that the number of combinations of $k$ elements from $n$, $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ , comes directly from that idea of "restricted factorial". Suppose you want to fill $k$ boxes with $n$ elements, you can thus put $n$ elements in the first box, $n-1$ elements in the second box, and so on until you can put $n-k+1$ elements in the last box. The division by $k!$ is simply to remove all the different ways the same elements could be put into the $k$ boxes.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of different notations for the rising and falling factorials; none appears to be completely standard.  Frequently one sees the *falling factorial* written using the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol):
$$
(x)_n = x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n+1).
$$
Here the subscript $n$ denotes the number of terms in the product, so your example is $(20)_{11}$.  Of course, the *rising factorial*,
$$
x^{(n)}=x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n-1),
$$
can express the same product: $10^{(11)}=(20)_{11}=20!/9!$.

Comment: It seems the definitions are swapped? Pochhammer is also the rising factorial according to the Wikipedia article

Comment: Per the article, the "Pochhammer symbol" is just the *notation* $(x)_n$, the meaning of which is different in different contexts.  E.g., apparently it denotes the falling factorial in combinatorics and the rising factorial in the theory of special functions.

Comment: thanks for clearing up!

Answer (score 2):

A non standard notation is $nPr$ where $nPr$= $n!/r!$, which is what you want.